# PHP Merge jpeg on top of png with alpha transparency

Tags: php, png, gd2

I am trying to put a jpeg behind a png - where the png has alpha transparency.

The foreground image is here: 
http://peugeot208.srv.good-morning.no/images/marker-shadow.png

The image behind is a facebook profile image - typically like this: 
https://graph.facebook.com/100000515495823/picture

The result image looses transparency and is black instead:
http://peugeot208.srv.good-morning.no/libraries/cache/test.png

This is the code I use:

```
// combine image with shadow
$newCanvas = imagecreatetruecolor(90,135);
$shadow = imagecreatefrompng("marker-shadow.png");  

//imagealphablending($newCanvas, false);
imagesavealpha($newCanvas, true);   

imagecopy($newCanvas, $canvas, 20, 23, 0, 0, 50, 50);
imagecopy($newCanvas, $shadow, 0, 0, 0, 0, 90, 135);
imagepng($newCanvas, $tempfile, floor($quality * 0.09));
```

If I enable imagealphablending($newCanvas, false);, the result is correct (with the hole in the middle of the marker being transparent) BUT the image behind is gone.

Can you shed light on this? :-)

Thanks!

**Edit: Found a solution**

I did some fiddling and ended up with this code - where the origin is not a createimagetruecolor but an image created from a template - which is a transparent png.

Now it works - the result is properly transparent. I don't really know why. Got an idea why?

**fbimage.php**

```
// Create markerIcon 
$src = $_REQUEST['fbid'];

$base_image = imagecreatefrompng("../images/marker-template.png");
$photo = imagecreatefromjpeg("https://graph.facebook.com/".$src."/picture");
$top_image = imagecreatefrompng("../images/marker-shadow.png");

imagesavealpha($base_image, true);
imagealphablending($base_image, true);

imagecopy($base_image, $photo, 20, 23, 0, 0, 50, 50);
imagecopy($base_image, $top_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, 90, 135);
imagepng($base_image, "./cache/".$src.".png");

?>

<img src="./cache/<?php echo $src ?>.png" />
```

**Update: Check the following code**
You can find the result here: http://peugeot208.srv.good-morning.no/images/marker.php
As you can see, the background is still black.

```
// create base image
$base_image = imagecreatetruecolor(90,135);
$photo = imagecreatefromjpeg("marker-original.jpg");
$top_image = imagecreatefrompng("marker-shadow.png");

imagesavealpha($top_image, true);
imagealphablending($top_image, true);

imagesavealpha($base_image, true);
imagealphablending($base_image, true);

// merge images
imagecopy($base_image, $photo, 20, 23, 0, 0, 50, 50);
imagecopy($base_image, $top_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, 90, 135);

// return file
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($base_image);
```

Comment: Make sure you've enabled alpha on the $canvas image as well.

Comment: Halfer. I didn't mean to seem sarcastic :-) I do need some direction with my previous questions though. I have asked 6 questions in total. One was wihout answers. Deleted. Take this question: 806133. The most reasonable answer is my own - but it is a workaround. Should I accept my own answer? Or somebody else's not sufficient answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution was to allocate a color as 100 % alpha transparent and then draw a square on the entire canvas of the base image:

```
// create base image
$base_image = imagecreatetruecolor(90,135);

// make $base_image transparent
imagealphablending($base_image, false);
$col=imagecolorallocatealpha($base_image,255,255,255,127);
imagefilledrectangle($base_image,0,0,90,135,$col);
imagealphablending($base_image,true);    
imagesavealpha($base_image, true);
// --- 

$photo = imagecreatefromjpeg("marker-original.jpg");
$top_image = imagecreatefrompng("marker-shadow.png");

// merge images
imagecopy($base_image, $photo, 20, 23, 0, 0, 50, 50);
imagecopy($base_image, $top_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, 90, 135);

// return file
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($base_image);
```

Comment: What solved this for me was line 8 "imagealphablending($base_image,true);" which came after the transparency layer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Run following php script and see weather https available on that array set.

```
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r(stream_get_wrappers());
    echo "</pre>";
```

out put will be like this.

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => php
        [1] => file
        [2] => glob
        [3] => data
        [4] => http
        [5] => ftp
        [6] => zip
        [7] => compress.zlib
        [8] => https
        [9] => ftps
        [10] => compress.bzip2
        [11] => phar
    )
```

here array element 8th shows https is enabled. If that not available on your code then. Find php.ini file and place following line there.

**extension=php_openssl.dll**

After that restart servers then your function will work with facebook resource url even.

Comment: It yielded the following: 

Array
(
    [0] => https
    [1] => ftps
    [2] => compress.zlib
    [3] => compress.bzip2
    [4] => php
    [5] => file
    [6] => glob
    [7] => data
    [8] => http
    [9] => ftp
    [10] => phar
    [11] => zip
)

Answer (score 0):

I try the following code it works well for me.

```
    $width = 400;
    $height = 400;

    $base_image = imagecreatefromjpeg("base.jpg");
    $top_image = imagecreatefrompng("top.png");

    imagesavealpha($top_image, false);
    imagealphablending($top_image, false);
    imagecopy($base_image, $top_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height);
    imagepng($base_image, "merged.png");
```

I check the first script. For all transparent png you have to apply following code.

imagesavealpha($shadow, true);
imagealphablending($shadow, true);

other wise that black coloured filling will be there. Here you didn't apply that for "marker-shadow.png" file object

Comment: For some reason this doesn't work when I try to first create a new image canvas -- se my code -- by running imagecreatetruecolor(..) The bg is still black.

Comment: I check your code (fbimage.php) its working fine. Only problem you are loading an facebook thum from https url. To make it work you have to enable https wrapers on php.ini file. But for local files it is working fine. I will put the instruction to enable https wraper as another answer.

Comment: Yes - fbimage.php works with me too. The difference (in my eyes) from fbimage.php and the first code I posted is that the first code uses imagecreatetruecolor as a base canvas, while fbimage.php uses a png as template with imagecreatefrompng.

Is there some code I should apply to the imagecreatetruecolor object to makt it behave the same way as the png template?

Comment: I check the first script. For all transparent png you have to apply following code. 

imagesavealpha($shadow, true);
imagealphablending($shadow, true);

other wise that black coloured filling will be there. Here you didn't apply that for "marker-shadow.png" file object

Answer (score 0):

Struggled with this for a while and none of the answers here helped me fully. Below is the code that worked perfectly when trying to slap JPG on top of transparent PNG (pay attention to the "// !!! ***" comments, they are important):

```
// create a true colour, transparent image
// turn blending OFF and draw a background rectangle in our transparent colour 
$image=imagecreatetruecolor($iwidth,$iheight);
imagealphablending($image,false);
$col=imagecolorallocatealpha($image,255,255,255,127);

imagefilledrectangle($image,0,0,$iwidth,$iheight,$col);
imagealphablending($image,true);
// ^^ Alpha blanding is back on.

// !!! *** IMAGE MANIPULATION STUFF BELOW ***

$backImage = imagecreatefrompng("yourimage.png");
imagecopyresampled($image, $backImage, 0, 0, 0, 0, 400, 300, 400, 300);
$foreImage = imagecreatefromjpeg("yourimage.png");
imagecopyresampled($image, $foreImage, 10, 10, 0, 0, 200, 150, 200, 150);

// !!! *** IMAGE MANIPULATION STUFF ABOVE ***

// output the results... 
header("Content-Type: image/png;");
imagealphablending($image,false);
imagesavealpha($image,true);
imagepng($image);
```

Credits: http://www.bl0g.co.uk/creating-transparent-png-images-in-gd.html

Answer (score 0):

```
// create base image
$photo = imagecreatefromjpeg("Penguins.jpg");
$frame = imagecreatefrompng("frame.png");

// get frame dimentions
$frame_width = imagesx($frame);
$frame_height = imagesy($frame);

// get photo dimentions
$photo_width = imagesx($photo);
$photo_height = imagesy($photo);

// creating canvas of the same dimentions as of frame
$canvas = imagecreatetruecolor($frame_width,$frame_height);

// make $canvas transparent
imagealphablending($canvas, false);
$col=imagecolorallocatealpha($canvas,255,255,255,127);
imagefilledrectangle($canvas,0,0,$frame_width,$frame_height,$col);
imagealphablending($canvas,true);    
imagesavealpha($canvas, true);

// merge photo with frame and paste on canvas
imagecopyresized($canvas, $photo, 0, 0, 0, 0, $frame_width, $frame_height,$photo_width, $photo_height); // resize photo to fit in frame
imagecopy($canvas, $frame, 0, 0, 0, 0, $frame_width, $frame_height);

// return file
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($canvas);

// destroy images to free alocated memory
imagedestroy($photo);
imagedestroy($frame);
imagedestroy($canvas);
```